# jQuery cross domain aAax plugin won't work with facebook.com

Tags: jquery

I don't know why but when I do:

```
$('body').load("http://facebook.com/");
```

It returns in console log:

> Error: data.results[0] is undefined

But if I do:

```
$('body').load("http://google.com/");
```

it works fine. Any ideas why?

Comment: FB redirects to www.Facebook.com, maybe that's why?

Comment: it may be that you are trying to access facebook.com while it may need the sub-domain (e.g. www.facebook.com)

Comment: Okay, sorry, didn't notice that

Comment: @Slaks: this plugin -> https://github.com/jamespadolsey/jQuery-Plugins/tree/master/cross-domain-ajax/

Comment: it's possible to do a cross domain in facebook.com? i mean using another plugin or techi~

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the Yahoo API is respecting a robots.txt constraint.  If you go to the URL below you will see an error that reads "Redirected to a robots.txt restricted URL: http://www.facebook.com"

[YQL Result](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=SELECT%20%2a%20FROM%20html%20WHERE%20url%20%3D%20%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%27&diagnostics=true)

Answer (score 0):

Trying to load data from remote domains is a violation of the Same Origin Policy.  You can learn more about this at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy.

In short, for security reasons browser's don't let you perform AJAX calls with domains external to the one you are currently on.  There are some workarounds for this limitation such as Server Side Proxies (http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html) and JSONP (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). Perhaps one of those technologies can help you.

Comment: If you inspect the plugin you will see that it uses a proxy(query.yahooapis.com)

Comment: Yikes! Can't believe I missed that.  Thanks for the heads up. Just posted a new answer.